# Joining two tables in mysql with where clause condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, say Employees and Date of Joining.Now  i want to  join both tables based on the employee id but i want to display the complete list of employees irrespective of whether Joining date is been registered or not..Here are the two tables

```
Employee
John                        
Paul                        
George
Ringo

DOJ
21/05/1998
23/02/2006
```

EmpIds being 1,2,3,4 for John,Paul,George,Ringo respectively

I need both the tables to be joined and the values of George and Ringo can be null but my main concern is i should be able to filter the DOJ. Please look below.

```
SELECT e.empName, d.DOJ, e.empId
FROM employee AS e
LEFT JOIN doj AS d ON e.empId = d.empId
WHERE d.doj BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('27/04/2000', '%d/%m/%Y')
  AND STR_TO_DATE('27/04/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Now when i run this query i get all the records filtered by the dates but i need all the employee names not just the ones filtered by where clause(with doj as null which i can replace as "not available"). I wish there was a full outer join option in mysql.

Comment: move the where condition to join `on`

Comment: To your last sentence:  http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this untested query:

```
SELECT e.empName, d.DOJ, e.empId
  FROM employee AS e
   left JOIN doj AS d ON e.empId = d.empId
and d.doj between STR_TO_DATE('27/04/2000', '%d/%m/%Y')and STR_TO_DATE('27/04/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')and STR_TO_DATE('27/04/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: thanx a lot it worked :) and also can you help me as to why mysql doest support full outer joins?

Comment: @KaranRamesh Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1604) maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you did everything right in your query apart from your where condition.
Based on your condition the result will be between the date of 27/04/2000 and 27/04/2014
so if the date value is "NULL" it won't be displayed.

Try the same query without that date condition you might get the result.